# Not able to login with api calling and not able to save the access id

Tags: ios, json, swift

This is my first application i am working on.I have one api url for login calling function. And when i enter username, password. It will generate one customer id.And i need to save that is, and i have to use that particular id for all my screen till user logged out.

But when i am doing api calling for login . Its not working. Please help me out.

This is my parameter passing  :

```
{
    "username" : "u@gmail.com",  
    "password" : "u123"
}
```

My json output after login api call :

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Login success.",
  "CustomerDetails": {
    "CustomerId": "1",
    "CustomerName": "u",
    "CustomerEmail": "u@gmail.com",
    "CustomerMobile": "901",
    "CustomerAddress": "#45, 7th main road."
  }
}
```

In this i need to save the `CustomerId` and i have to use that `CustomerId` to all my screens.

My api calling fuction while login button tap :

```
  func getcartdetaildata () {
        let headers = [
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "postman-token": "4c933910-0da0-b199-257b-28fb0b5a89ec"
        ]

        let jsonObj:Dictionary<String, Any> = [

                "username" : "\(UsernameEmail)",
                "password" : "\(Password)"

        ]


        if (!JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonObj)) {
            print("is not a valid json object")
            return
        }

        if let postData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObj, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted) {
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://Login.php")! as URL,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            request.httpBody = postData

            let session = URLSession.shared
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    ///print(error)
                } else {

                    print("123.......... ")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                        if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                        {

                            print(json)

                            let status = json["status"] as? Int;
                            if(status == 1)
                            {
                                print("asdasdasx.......... ")

                               // let access_token = json["CustomerId"]

                                //print(access_token)
                                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

//                                    
//                                    
//                                    //Set logged in to true
//                                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ISLOGGEDIN")
//                                    
//                                    //Set access token
//                                    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(access_token, forKey: "CustomerId")
//                                    
//                                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
//                                    


                                    })

                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            })

            dataTask.resume()
        }
    }
```

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: why use 2 time DispatchQueue ?

Comment: Measn that ???. Should i need to remove any 1

Comment: What is it not working; I mean what the error?

Comment: UserDefaults.standard.set(json["CustomerDetails"]["CustomerId"] as String, forKey: "CustomerId")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

Comment: i have removed that. But still my status is 0.

Comment: See my comment its store customer_id to UserDefaults

Comment: if i enter the correct login username, password also its showing wrong username, password. And in my code i try to print (json). I am getting status = o.

Comment: My problem is not only for storing the customer id. But i am not try to login too

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya  one more doubt. In other screen how can i call the saved customer id . I mean how to call in other screen the saved customer id

Comment: WHen your customer id genreate at that time store it into NSUDerdeafult so you can access it everywhere

Comment: Thats why i am asking how can i call that saved customer id in my login screen nsuser default. And how can i call that

Comment: But initially, my login functionality itself not working . Please help me in that

Comment: @jeo now check my answer your problem will be solve

Answer (score 0):

```
func apicalling () {

    let Username:NSString = EmailTextField.text! as NSString
    let password:NSString = PasswordTextField.text! as NSString

    let headers = [
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "4c933910-0da0-b199-257b-28fb0b5a89ec"
    ]
    let parameters = [
             "username": "\(Username)",
            "password": "\(password)"
    ]
    do {
        let postData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options :[])
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://Login.php")! as URL,cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = postData

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                ///print(error)
            } else {

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            if let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])) as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                    {
                        let status = json["status"] as? Int;
                        if(status == 1)
                        {
                           print(json)
                          }

                    }
                })
             }
        })

        dataTask.resume()



    } catch {
        // print("JSON serialization failed:  \(error)")
    }
}
```

**Code for save data in NSUserDefaults.**

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setValue(YOUR_VALUE, forKey: "PASSKEY")
userDefaults.synchronize() // don't forgot this line
```

**Retriving data from NSUserDefaults**

```
if let VARIABLE = userDefaults.valueForKey("PASSKEY") {
    // do something here when a Data exists
}
else {
    // no data exists
}
```

Comment: I ma passing the parameter like this `let parameters = [
                "username" : "\(emailfield!.text)",
                "password" : "\(passwordField!.text)"
                

            ]`  if i give any static data its give status = 1. But if i pass the value parameters dynamically its not showing the correct status

Comment: And one more thing. U have give some solution for saving the customer id in userdefault. But how can i pass that or use that saved nsuserdefault customer id in other screen or other class

Comment: For example, in my home screen i need to pass this customer id to api. Then how can i pass this saved nsuser default customer id. And how can i call in other vc classses

Comment: Let variable  = UserDeafult. standard.valurforkey("CustomerId") in which controller you want your customer id just write this and you can access it anywhere .

Comment: For reterving the data from nsuser default is fine. But you have stored it in `if let VARIABLE = userDefaults.valueForKey("PASSKEY") ` right ?. Its possible to declare that let variable globally ??. And to use `if self.VARIABLE = userDefaults.valueForKey("PASSKEY")`

Comment: @jeo ya possible it and did your log in problem solve with parameter that i show in my answer is there true then approve it and up vote it .thank you.